# Got code 422 error when convert cURL to google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, httprequest, urlencode, x-www-form-urlencoded

Here is what the document says:

Use the code parameter value to make the following request to the OAuth token endpoint in the API with the authorization_code grant type:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.deliverr.com/oauth/v1/token' \\
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \\
--data-urlencode 'code={received_code_value}' \\
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

And I tried to use google app script
make the code like below

```
function testGetToken(){
  var url = "https://api.staging.deliverr.com/oauth/v1/token"
  /*const payload = {
      'code':'this is code',
      'grant-type':'authorization_code'
  };*/
  var headers = {
            "code": "this is code",
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        };
  const options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'header': headers
      //'payload': payload
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

No matter I put code and grant_type to payload or header
They all return same message

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.staging.deliverr.com returned code 422. 
Truncated server response: 
{"code":422,"message":"{"fields":{"request.grant_type":
{"message":"'grant_type' is required"}}}\n
Please refer to Deliverr API documentation... 
(use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

What is going on for my code? Is that urlencode problem or something else? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://api.deliverr.com/oauth/v1/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'code={received_code_value}' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code'
  ```
- You have already confirmed that your curl command worked fine.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function testGetToken() {
  const url = "https://api.deliverr.com/oauth/v1/token";
  const payload = {
    'code': '{received_code_value}',
    'grant-type': 'authorization_code'
  };
  const options = { payload };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

- When `payload` is used with UrlFetchApp, the POST method is automatically used.
- The default content type of the request header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- In your curl command, the data is sent as the form.

#### Note:

- I think that the request of the above sample script is the same as your curl command. But, if an error occurs, please confirm your `'{received_code_value}'` and `'authorization_code'` again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)